# Binding to template property inside a DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, binding, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a custom control as follows:

```
<CustomControl>
    <CustomControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </CustomControl.ContentTemplate>
</CustomControl>
```

In the control template of the CustomControl, I try to bind to the CustomControl.ContentTemplate from within a DataTemplate, but it does not work:

```
<ListBox
ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResultsList}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ContentControl
                Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
            </ContentControl>
            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding HierarchyPath}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="->"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note: **ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"**

I know that you cannot use TemplateBinding inside a Datatemplate, even though the DataTemplate is inside a control template.  But does anyone know how to achieve what I want to achieve without using TemplateBinding?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle, and use it to make a ControlTemplate.

Something like this:

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style  TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ContentControl
                            Content="{Binding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
                        </ContentControl>
                        <ItemsControl
                            ItemsSource="{Binding HierarchyPath}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="->"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That does not seem to work.  It is still not binding to my ContentTemplate.  I only see the string represenation of the Content object, but not the name of the object.

Comment: After a re-read of your original question, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.  Can you provide all of the xaml for your customcontrol?

Comment: That is essentially all of my XAML.  What I'm trying to do is to use CustomControl in various different places.  However, there is a section of the CustomControl that needs to look different in different usages.  So, I'm trying to make it so that I can define a different ContentTemplate when I create an instance of the CustomControl.  That ContentTemplate needs to be displayed somewhere in the CustomControl ControlTemplate style (i.e. in the ListBox).  So what I tried to do is to display that custom content as a ContentControl.

Comment: Originally, I just did this:
<ListBox
ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResultsList}"
ItemTemplate="{Binding ContentTemplate}"/>

which works great.  It will display the content I defined as part of the style.  However, now I need to add more to the ItemTemplate (i.e. I need to add the ItemsControl)  So, I tried to display the ContentTemplate using a ContentControl instead, but that is not working.

Comment: This can't be all of your xaml... I mean, if you created a custom control, and defined an implicit style for it, then I need to see the whole implicit style.  The syntax depends heavily on how exactly you constructed this.